# PageTransformer returns a wrong position, When deleting the page from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I want to implement this animation in my ViewPager
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bhaveshjabuvani88/CarouselEffect/master/CarouselEffectDemo.gif

Everything works fine until I try to remove view from ViewPager.
I have 3 pages in ViewPager. When I'm removing page N2, position in `transformPage(View view, float position)` for page N1 and page N3 is becoming 0.0.
Therefore, the position for center page (page N3) is becoming negative:

`position -= parent.getPaddingRight() / (float) pageWidth;`
and center page is scaling down.

Can you help to fix this problem ?

```
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
    int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

    // FIX issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64046
    ViewPager parent = (ViewPager) view.getParent();
    position -= parent.getPaddingRight() / (float) pageWidth;

    float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
    float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
    float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
    if (position < 0) {
        view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
    } else {
        view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
    }

    // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
    view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
    view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

    // Fade the page relative to its size.
    if (position >= -1 && position <= 1) {
        view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA + (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) / (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));
    } else {
        view.setAlpha(1F);
    }

}
```

Comment: have you called PagerAdapter's notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: yes, I have called it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can reproduce reliably but not 100%.